# C# Store Regex results in array

Tags: c#, regex

Is it possible in C# to store Regex results in Array, so each member will store each Regex match

Like in Python:

```
text="A text is"
a=re.findall("[A-Z/a-z]+",text)
print(a[:]) //If write print(a[0]) it will return 'A', a[1] will give 'text', a[2] 'is', a[:] prints whole results
```

So is it possible to store regex results in C#, so each member of array would consist from each match
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Regex.Matches` method. This will return a `MatchCollection` that contains all the matches. The text of the match is the `Value` property of each item (`Match`) of that collection.

So, using the equivalent of your sample:

```
var text = "A text is";
var matches = Regex.Matches(text, "[A-Za-z]+);

matches[0].Value.Dump();
```

Comment: For reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

yes. just surround with parentheses the values. and then access the groups array.

```
Match match = Regex.Match("abc","(a)(b)(c)");
string a = match.Groups[1].Value;
```